# How to write 4 bytes of data to sigma dsp ADAU1452 from Pic32?

Tags: signal-processing, i2c, pic32

I am trying to write 4 bytes of data from Pic32 to SigmaDsp ADAU1452 over I2C Bus. According to sigma dsp datasheet I have to do the following:

Send device address = 0x70

Send Register address. The register I am trying to write to is "0x0021"

SubAddress Byte 1 = 0x00

SubAddress Byte 2 = 0x21

Data Bytes = 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

Would it be correct to send 4 bytes of Data to 2 bytes of address? I think this is not possible.
Can someone please tell me how I can write these 4 bytes to the register address 0x0021?

Comment: The address you provide in an I2C write transaction is a *starting* address.  You can generally write as many bytes as you want, with the address automatically incrementing, and possibly even wrapping around if you hit the end of the device's address space.

Comment: Hi I tested it and it works I can right 4 bytes to the 2 bytes address. But I am confused that if the address increments is it still pointing to the same register I intend to write to?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the address increment works in such a way that *it's actually possible to use the chip*.